# How to get response headers - Issue with getting response headers

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient, response-headers

I'm passing pagination information in response header and unable to get using following method in angular 8. I'm getting `0` all the time but in response showing diffrent value. Can anyone let me know where I made mistake?

**app.service.ts**

```js
  indexBooking(perPage: number, page: number) {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/prices`, {
        params: formatParameters({perPage, page}),
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res) => ({
          max: Number.parseInt(res.headers.get('x-total-count'), 10) || 0,
          index: Number.parseInt(res.headers.get('x-next-page'), 10) || 0,
          page: Number.parseInt(res.headers.get('x-per-page'), 10) || 20,
          items: res.body,
        })),
      );
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  merge(this.paginator.page)
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.bookingService.indexBooking(this.paginator.pageSize, this.paginator.pageIndex);
      }),
      map((data) => {
        console.log('data', data);
        this.resultsLength = data.items.length;
        return data.items;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return observableOf([]);
      }),
    )
    .subscribe((data) => (this.data = data));
}
```

**Response Header Image**

[image]

Comment: you are doing it right. can't see anything wrong

Comment: yeah, weird. I dont know why can't get response header

Comment: is it possible to put up a stackblitz with your api?

Comment: @joyBlanks, I'll try. Need to bypass security layer. thanks

Comment: https://www.mocky.io try this. Use custom headers

Comment: You can get http header response using  observe: 'response' as 'body'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your backend to expose your custom response headers.

Taken from [Mozilla Docs on Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers):

> The Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.
>
> By default, only the 6 CORS-safelisted response headers are exposed:
>
> Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to list them using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Therefore, you have to code your backend to set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` such that it returns:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-total-count, x-next-page, x-per-page`

OR

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *`

Here's a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mxxpt) for you to explore, you can observe in the StackBlitz's console that I can retrieve Etag headers but **not** X-Frame-Options because https://api.github.com has set `Access-Contorl-Expose-Headers` to expose Etag but not X-Frame-Options:

[image]

Comment: You can also use [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) to add a response header to your API endpoint. It will help you to test the header locally without making any changes in the backend. Here's the rule you are looking for - https://app.requestly.in/rules/#sharedList/1570154817985-add-access-control-header. **Note - You must have Requestly installed to access above rule**

Comment: Heya @SKL, If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).